# How do I redirect in angularjs interceptor, except not on error?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

I want to check if a CSRF cookie token is present, and if it's not, redirect to login.

Not having a cookie however wouldn't trigger `requestError`, so I can't put it in there.

I'm sure I could simply stick it in `request`, but I want to do this  'cleanly' and not a dirty redirect that's going to cause a ton of errors to possibly bubble up in console because I'm redirecting mid-promise-chain.

Note: I'm not using angular to manage authentication. I'm simply going to let the backend handle that via a standard POST form on the marketing site. That's why its using `window.location.href` and not `$location.path()`.

```
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q, $cookies) {
    return {
      request: function(config) {
        if ($cookies.get(xsrfCookieName) && $cookies.get(tokenCookieName)) {
          return config;
        } else {
          // can I do something here to redirect cleanly?
        }
      },
      responseError: function(rejection) {
        if (rejection.status === 401) {
          window.location.href = '/login';
        }
        return $q.reject(rejection);
      }
    };
  });
```

Comment: I'm using https://github.com/witoldsz/angular-http-auth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) (emphasis mine):

> requestError: interceptor gets called when a **previous interceptor
>   threw an error or resolved with a rejection**.

So you could reject and create a rejection with status 401 from your `request`:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q, $cookies) {
  return {
    request: function(config) {
      if ($cookies.get(xsrfCookieName) && $cookies.get(tokenCookieName)) {
        return config;
      } else {
        return $q.reject({
          status: 401
        });
      }
    },
    responseError: function(rejection) {
      if (rejection.status === 401) {
        window.location.href = '/login';
      }
      return $q.reject(rejection);
    }
  };
});
```